# No Sound from Altec Lansing ADA 745 Speakers

Tags: audio, speakers

I have an old set of Altec Lansing ADA745 speakers (a subwoofer and four satellite speakers).  The satellite speakers plug into the back of the subwoofer which has a pair of thin cables that connect to a split adapter with black and light green connectors ending in a single green plug that fits in the standard sized headphone port.  The unit powers on, green light on the satellite speaker and hum from the subwoofer, but I get no sound from any of them no matter what I plug this into.  I have tried a pair of computers and tried plugging it into my phone just to see if I could get any sound. Nothing works.  Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might try to get audio out of this set?  Any recommendations or suggestions would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: There are several suggestions on fixya.com at [Limited volume on speakers. Worked well previously.](https://www.fixya.com/support/t125711-limited_volume_speakers_worked) You might find [How to Spot Faulty Capacitors](https://www.robotroom.com/Faulty-Capacitors-1.html) useful.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will check that out.